# Not testing public methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tdd

General advice I've seen regarding TDD from books such as [POODR](http://www.poodr.com/) is to not test private methods. The idea is that public methods that call the private methods will be tested and that should be good enough to verify the private methods.

This makes sense but what about cases where the private methods are several "layers" deep? Here's a contrived example of what I mean:

```
public

# test this method
def foo
  private1
end

private

def private1
  private2
end

def private2
  private3
end

def private3
  # does stuff
end
```

I don't have a real world example to share but in cases like this, is it still good enough to just test the public method `foo`? Or is code constructed like this pointing to a possibly deeper problem?

Comment: Well, general advice is 'in general'. This advice may be true maybe in more than 90% of the cases, but at times, you may be a part of the minority that may need to see what suits you best. <br/>

Answer (score 3):

The idea behind this is that the internals of a class are implementation details of that class.

Your contrived example only exposes the output from foo to the user. So that's the only thing your tests have to make sure doesn't change.

If you DRY up the whole class with 10 methods like foo to only use one method internally you wouldn't want to see any tests break because you changed to privates. As long as the public interface still works there is no need to test the internals.

**The principle behind this is encapsulation.** You don't care what your class does under the covers - for all you are concerned it can run on a quantum computer and send it's data stream to a man on the moon to do the calculation - as long as the output is correct your users will see a correct and expected result.

Any attempt to test the privates will only lead to tests that break once you change these methods.
That's fine in a lot of cases, but over-testing makes you spend far more time fixing broken tests than being productive, so this rule is mostly there to give you some wiggle-room.

Of course this advice always depends: If you feel it's important that this one method works you might want to write tests for it. But those tests are mostly duplication of tests you already had in place for the public methods anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I'd still only test #foo, because it is the only method other objects depend upon. If your tests "prove" that foo does what it is supposed to, it doesn't matter how many private methods are called to accomplish this.

You might like this talk by Sandy Metz that further illustrates testing techniques: 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URSWYvyc42M

But I get your concerns. If you feel insecure about one of your private methods, it's ok to write some tests to feel more confident about the method, but don't waste too much time maintaining these tests.

Say you change some implementation details and now the tests for #private2 fail, but the tests for #foo are still green, I would not spend too much time trying to fix #private2. (In other words, delete the tests for #private2)

Answer (score 0):

I think testing the function foo is enough to test other private functions. I don't find any issues with deep level of function calling. Foo function as a unit should work for all assertions.

Answer (score 0):

Testing the public interface only makes sense, because you want to make sure that external interaction with your code is safe and works as expected while you want to maintain a reasonable amount of flexibility to change the implementation without changing your tests.

If you then think a concept comprised in your private methods is complex or interesting enough, you may want to turn it into separate classes, create new public interfaces and write tests for those.
There are lots of advises out there to help you determine when to clean up clases such as [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) principles

Don't ever think about writing tests, or code likewise,  you don't intend to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

**I don't always go by the book. Sometimes needs/requirements also dictate your approach.**

Just a few days back i came across this scenario. Though i was working on `Java` code, and my answer is based on Java, it may still be relevant no matter what programming language you consider.

While trying to achieve a good code coverage for an existing (old) huge class (which had <40% code coverage), i had to write several test cases, and thus noticed a few things:

1) Few methods which should have been 'private', were given 'default' (package level) access modifiers just so that they could be tested.(Using JUnit 4)
*---Turned out to be a wrong approach as those methods 'SHOULD' have been 'private'. I had to change them to 'private' and modify the test cases.*

2) To increase code coverage, i had to call the public method and test the 'private' methods which were deep down. For this, I had to read/understand the entire huge class. (This class had just 2 public methods, and about 15-20 private methods, with few method calls being 4-5 'levels' deep). 
*---As you may have figured out, this was turning out to be too complex. No doubt a lot of these private methods were getting too difficult to be tested* :(

Finally i was tired of reading all this old code and went ahead with testing each and every method individually (Using 'Reflection' to test private methods). In an old and huge system, this made a lot of sense. 
My every unit test ensured that it was just testing only one method for its correctness.
 **It's very easy to fix any error this way if any method fails to do what it was intended to.**

Of course, arguments can be made here saying that encapsulation should be respected and my test cases should have only called the public methods. 
**But then, what when there is a private method which is 5 levels deep down which is not doing what was expected of it? How do you find this bug in an old and legacy code!!! Wouldn't you wish that every method was tested?** 
And in this case, the class had no chance of its business logic being changed. Thus there was no question of maintaining the Test Class. 
*And though this class was a great candidate for numerous refactorings, you wouldn't want to take it up when you are nearing code freeze!* :)

**In short, the answer can differ case-by-case. You/Your team would be the best decision maker for this based on your needs/requirements as you would be the ones who best understand your system...** hopefully ;)